# Split string and remove the second half

Tags: php, string, replace, split

I have a string like so:

```
$variable = "here is<br/>my code";
```

I want to trash anything after the  `<br/>`. How can I go about this?

Comment: Use `explode` or a regular expression.

Comment: Or juse `strpos()` and `substr()`.

Comment: can't you just try any string function in PHP?

Comment: The accepted answer to that question should work with a multiple character string as well as a single character, but the higher voted strtok answer will not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo strtok('here is<br/>my code','<') . '<br/>';
```

Output:

```
here is<br/>
```

With the caveat that the split here is on the `<` character not necessarily a `<br/>`.